# Query works against MySQL on windows, but not on Mysql on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, windows, vb.net, ubuntu-18.04

I have an application that uses the `datasource` function to output lines on a `datagridview`

```
dim query1 as string = "Select * from trades"
Source1.DataSource = GetData(query1)

With Me.DGVTrades
    .DataSource = Source1
End With
```

When I run the application against a `MySQL` server hosted on `windows 10` the code above works and fills my `datagridview`. However, it doesn't work for a `MySQL` server hosted on `ubuntu 18.04`.

The databases and MySQL server versions(8.0.11) are the same for both OS, since I used the same dump file to import the data on either servers.

**Question:** What could be causing this problem?

**Update:** There is another query that uses the same connection string that fills another DGV using the same method mentioned above and this one seems to be working.

After speaking with Terry, I realized the problem is in the query, when I run the query using the workbench in MySQL, it works on the windows server, but not on the Ubuntu server

Comment: Error output?  Is your connection pointed at the right database?  Does your user have grants from your query source IP address?  Lots of questions.

Comment: is the connection string to the database correct for the ubuntu machine with proper permissions

Comment: Do you have a try/catch block? Is it throwing an error? Set a breakpoint and see if the Source1 actually contains any records.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question. so the error isn't in the sql query or in the connection string, because it works perfectly on the windows OS. On the Ubuntu OS it works for the first table and comes back empty from the second table. I am using two different datasource function

Comment: @TerryCarmen I can't use try catch block on it because someone wrote over a thousand lines under `on error resume next`, when i comment that out the application doesn't even function..lol

Comment: @Anirban - In Visual Studio, turn on "Break on all Common Language Runtime (CLR) exceptions" You'll need to google the location of the option because it moved around between versions. Once you do that, find every place that has an unhandled exception and deal with it properly. The application isn't "working" right now; you just can't see the broken parts.

Comment: @TerryCarmen +1, i found the error following your steps! the sql syntax doesn't work on Ubuntu, but works on windows.

`select 'all' as Group_name from Groups Union Select distinct Group_Name from groups where trim(Group_Name) <> '' and Group_Name <> 'ALL'`

Comment: Cool! Glad to help!

Comment: @Anirban you might also want to look at the quotes.  Some DB drivers/environments are fussier or more forgiving about the quotes. Make sure you have the right kind in each spot (back tick, single quote, double quote, etc.). Also you might want to retype all the quotes anyway if you've copied or pasted any code. Some character sets have characters that look exactly like what you expect but aren't.

Comment: @TerryCarmen I answered the question below, it wasn't working because the table names in the query had capital letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I found is in the MySQL table names, there is some case sensitivity in the Ubuntu server. Alot of the query in my code is written with capital letters in the table name, that's why it doesn't work on the MySQL on Ubuntu. However MySQL on windows seem to be more forgiving about this and accepts the table names as is.

"How table and database names are stored on disk and used in MySQL is affected by the lower_case_table_names system variable. lower_case_table_names can take the values shown in the following table. This variable does not affect case sensitivity of trigger identifiers. On Unix, the default value of lower_case_table_names is 0. On Windows, the default value is 1. On macOS, the default value is 2." 
<--Source --> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html